# Applying stretch in ArcGIS Image Analysis Window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, color, image-analysis

I need to apply stretch to ArcGIS 10.1 exported raster. The best way to accomplish this task: [Image Analysis Window](http://goo.gl/E39LR), because there are fine tools to equalize raster data.

1 - This is my IRS-P6 24m cell size, Landsat's ETM+ equivalent. My goal: export the raster with histogram stretch:

[image: Raster with ArcGIS 10 Color Balance]

Full Resolution: http://goo.gl/0KlvS

2 - Now we have the exported raster. Unfortunately, the exported raster does not save equalization or color balance adjusted in the original raster data. The file was exported without histogram curves.

[image: Exported Raster without color balance]

Full Resolution: http://goo.gl/PWpG0

So, the only function of the ArcGIS 10.1 Image Analysis stretch is for visualization?

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely *supposed* to be able to do this.  The blockquote below is from the end of this [ESRI blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/08/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/):

> Creating your display by using the Image Analysis window instead of
>   mosaic datasets results in a temporary raster. If you want to keep
>   your results, export the layer that you added the functions to from
>   ArcMap. To do this, right-click the layer in the table of contents and
>   click Export Data. The data you save can now be added to an ArcMap
>   session and will display with the final results.

Comment: Ok Dude, I try this way many times, but the Export Data menu does not save the stretch. The ESRI's blog shows the technique to convert colormap to RGB. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong - maybe it's a 10.1 thing, but the work in that blog post creates a new 'temporary' layer with a pansharpening function and it saved *WITH* the changes to disk for me.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is - in the Export Data dialog box select the option to 'Use Renderer'.
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34949